# How to clear the text field after performing??? KivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

After performing an operation, for example, receiving text and closing the window, when opening the window in the text field text.
It is necessary that after closing the mdDialog window, the text is erased. I manage to save it, but in the string method. It must be erased by pressing the button and closing.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


KV = '''


<Content>
    tes:tes
    orientation: 'vertical'
    spacing: '12dp'
    size_hint_y: None
    height: '120dp'
    MDTextField:
        id:tes

        on_text:app.inputs(self)
        





MDFloatLayout:
    MDFloatingActionButton:
        icon:'plus'
        pos_hint:{'center_y': .1, 'center_x':.5}
        on_release:app.new()



'''


class Content(BoxLayout):
    pass




class General(MDApp):
    dialog=None 

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)




    def inputs(self, event):
        self.txt = event.text
        print(self.txt)



    def no(self, event):
        event.text=''
        self.dialog.dismiss()
        
        
    def yes(self, event):
        event.text=''
        self.dialog.dismiss()


    def new(self):
        if not self.dialog:
            self.dialog = MDDialog(
                type='custom',
                content_cls=Content(),
                buttons = [
                    MDFlatButton(text='Отмена', text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color, on_release=self.no),
                    MDFlatButton(text='Добавить',text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color, on_press=self.yes),
                    
                ]
            )
        self.dialog.open()
        






General().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Good day.
I recommend you create `text_field_text = StringProperty("My Default String")` in your `App` class and let the `widget.text = app.text_field_text`.

From there, you could clear your app string property with the callback function.